# Select count query or computed column

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

So, i have 2 tables:

**Categories table**

```
Analit  int 
PositionInMenu  int
```

**Item table**

```
Analit  int 
CategoryAn  int
```

So, i have about 50 categories and 2000 items. I need to take for each category count of items it includes.

***1)***`SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(Analit) FROM Item_table t2 WHERE t2.CategoryAn = t1.Analit) as tCount FROM Categories_table t1 ORDER BY PositionInMenu`

***2)*** Add into Categories table computed column with function call:

```
([dbo].[Categories_GetItemsCountInCategory]([Analit]))
```

and function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Categories_GetItemsCountInCategory
    (   
    @categoryId int = null
    )
RETURNS int
AS
    BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT COUNT(Analit) 
            FROM Items 
            WHERE CategoryAn = @categoryId)
    END
```

And then i can simply take value of added column into my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Categories_table
ORDER BY PositionInMenu
```

**So, the question**. What's better for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pretty much always better off having data access inline in the query rather than in scalar UDFs.

The query optimiser does not expand out scalar (or multi statement) UDFs so you always enforce a nested loops join plan rather than allowing it to consider alternatives.

You could also consider an `OUTER JOIN ... GROUP BY` rather than a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t1.*,
       ISNULL(tCount, 0) AS tCount
FROM   Categories_table t1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(Analit) AS tCount,
                         CategoryAn
                  FROM   Item_table
                  GROUP  BY CategoryAn) t2
         ON t2.CategoryAn = t1.Analit
ORDER  BY PositionInMenu
```

Comment: The OP is suggesting a computed column (populated with a UDF)

Comment: @Andomar - This wouldn't be permitted as a persisted computed column and as non persisted my answer still applies. It is just like having the UDF referenced directly in the query.

Comment: Ok, nice. But, i'm using LINQ and it generate sql query, not always very clean. There is too much LINQ in my project and it's too hard to rewrite now every function in clean sql query. Mb later, thx.

Comment: @FSou1: sounds like overoptimization to me: With 50 categories and 2000 items and some good indexes the sql generated by Linq2sql will perform fine. Just have a look at your loadoptions to make sure you do not get lazy loading (N+1) but a one time sql with proper joins.